# What does the following prolog code exactly (Line by line)do?

Tags: prolog

```
win(Board, Player) :-
    append(_, [Column | _], Board),
    check_column(Column, Player).

% Horizontal win condition
win(Board, Player) :-
    append(_, [Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 | _], Board),
    check_rows(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Player).

% Diagonal win condition type 1 (decreasing rows)
win(Board, Player) :-
    append(_, [Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 | _], Board),
    Col2 = [_ | NewCol2],`enter code here`
    Col3 = [_, _ | NewCol3],
    Col4 = [_, _, _ | NewCol4],
    check_rows(Col1, NewCol2, NewCol3, NewCol4, Player).
```

Comment: But what about Prolog,In fact i want to  Know the logic behind the instructions

Answer (score 0):

```
win(Board, Player) :-
    append(_, [Column | _], Board),
    check_column(Column, Player).
```

This defines a rule for when the predicate `win(Board, Player)` is true. It says "`win` with variables `Board` and `Player` is true, if ..."

The next two lines define the two conditions that have two hold for it to be true. So the rule says "`win` with variables `Board` and `Player` is true, if `append(_, [Column | _], Board)` is true and `check_column(Column, Player)` is true."

The `append` predicate is provided by Prolog ([link](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append/3)). It takes three lists and is true when the concatenation of the first two lists is equal to the third list. So `append(List1, List2, List3)` is true if `List3` is equal to the concatenation of `List1` and `List2`.

The `_` is used for variables we do not care about. Note that each `_` refers to a separate variable we do not care about, so if you see multiple `_`, they are unrelated to each other.

The list unpacking syntax `[X | XS]` refers to a list where the first element is `X` and the remaining list is `XS`. So for `[X|XS] = [1,2,3]`, you would get `X = 1` and `XS = [2,3]`. So `[Column | _]` means "some list that has `Column` as the first element and where we do not care about the remaining list".

Therefore, `append(_, [Column | _], Board)` is true if `Board` is the concatenation of some list we do not care about (the first `_`) and another list whose first element is `Column` and where we do not care about the remaining list `_`. In other words, `append(_, [Column | _], Board)` is true if `Column` is some element of the list `Board`.

Since you did not specify the definition `check_column`, I cannot say what `check_column(Column, Player)` means. I would guess that it specifies some kind of winning condition. So `check_column(Column, Player)` would be true if `Column` is a column of the board where `Player` wins.

In conclusion, the rule says: "`win(Board, Player)` is true if there is a `Column` in `Board`, such that `Player` wins `Column`".

```
% Horizontal win condition
win(Board, Player) :-
    append(_, [Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 | _], Board),
    check_rows(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Player).
```

This defines a second rule for when `win(Board, Player)` is true. If the first rule is not satisfied, Prolog will try the second rule.

Here we see an extended list unpacking. An expression of the form `[X,Y | XS]` means a list that has `X` as the first element and `Y` as the second element, and `XS` as the remaining list. So `[X,Y | XS] = [1,2,3,4]` would give you `X = 1`, `Y = 2` and `XS = [3,4]`.

Therefore, `append(_, [Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 | _], Board)` is true if `Board` is the concatenation of some list we do not care about and another list that starts with `Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4` and where we do not care about the remaining list. In other words, it is true if `Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4` are four adjacent columns somewhere in `Board`.

Again, I do not know your definition of `check_rows`. I would assume it again defines some kind of winning condition that has to hold in `Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4` for `Player` to win.

In conclusion, the rule says: "`win(Board, Player)` is true if there are four adjacent columns where `Player` wins".

```
% Diagonal win condition type 1 (decreasing rows)
win(Board, Player) :-
    append(_, [Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 | _], Board),
    Col2 = [_ | NewCol2],
    Col3 = [_, _ | NewCol3],
    Col4 = [_, _, _ | NewCol4],
    check_rows(Col1, NewCol2, NewCol3, NewCol4, Player).
```

This defines a third rule for when `win(Board, Player)` is true. Prolog will try this rule if the first two rules did not succeed.

As before, `append(_, [Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 | _], Board)` is true if `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3`, `Col4` are four adjacent columns in `Board`.

The expression `Col2 = [_ | NewCol2]` does a list unpacking of `Col2`, where the first element is ignored (the `_`) and the remaining list is called `NewCol2`. So if `Col2 = [1,2,3,4]`, then `Col2 = [_ | NewCol2]` gives you `NewCol2 = [2,3,4]`. In other words, `NewCol2` is `Col2` with the first element removed.

The expressions `Col3 = [_, _ | NewCol3]` and `Col4 = [_, _, _ | NewCol4]` are similar, except that for `Col3` the first two elements are removed and for `Col4`, the first three elements are removed.

Here is a sketch to make it more clear:

[image]

Again I can only guess what `check_rows(Col1, NewCol2, NewCol3, NewCol4, Player)` does, but I would assume it checks some kind of winning condition for `Col1`, `NewCol2`, `NewCol3`, `NewCol4`.

---

Looking at the rules now, I would infer that this might be for a [Connect Four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connect_Four)-style game. In that case, the `check_column(Column, Player)` predicate should be true if `Column` contains four adjacent pieces belonging to `Player`. The `check_rows(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Player)` predicate would be true if the four columns each have a piece belonging to `Player` in the same row. The same predicate is then also used to check for (decreasing) diagonals, by removing leading elements from `Col2`, `Col3`, `Col4`. If the `check_rows` predicate finds a piece belonging to `Player` in the same row of each of those reduced columns, this would translate to a (decreasing) diagonal in the unreduced columns.